# Javascript and Ajax each row 3 different Total Calculations not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is the script used by ajax library and javascript.

Total order column Total price working fine.
But 
Total Calculations for the discount column and net price column not working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row1').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1c = $(this).val() * 25;
        $('.row1c').html((row1c).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row1a').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1ac = $(this).val() * 15;
        $('.row1ac').html((row1ac).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row1b').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1bc = $(this).val() * 10;
        $('.row1bc').html((row1bc).toFixed(2));

    });

   $('.row2').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2c = $(this).val() * 45;
        $('.row2c').html((row2c).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row2a').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2ac = $(this).val() * 25;
        $('.row2ac').html((row2ac).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row2b').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2bc = $(this).val() * 20;
        $('.row2bc').html((row2bc).toFixed(2));

    });
  $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row5c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })


  $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row55c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })
   $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row555c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })
});


</script>

<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" align="center">


  <tr>
    <th>Cracker Name</th>
    <th>Cracker Photo</th>
    <th>Packing Model</th>
    <th>Retail Price</th>
    <th>You Save (Discount - 60%) <br /></th>

    <th>Selling Price<br /></th>

    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total Order</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
    <th>Net Price</th>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>3.5'' Laxmi</td>
    <td>--</td>
    <td>5 in 1 Packet</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pages" class="row1 row1a row1b" />    </td>
    <td><span class="row1c">0.00</span>    </td>
      <td><span class="row1ac">0.00</span>    </td>
        <td><span class="row1bc">0.00</span>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.5'' Laxmi</td>
    <td>--</td>
    <td>5 in 1 Packet</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pages" class="row2 row2a row2b" />    </td>
    <td><span class="row2c">0.00</span>    </td>
      <td><span class="row2ac">0.00</span>    </td>
        <td><span class="row2bc">0.00</span>    </td>
  </tr>






  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" align="right">Total  </td>

    <td><span class="row5c">0.00</span>    </td>
     <td><span class="row55c">0.00</span>    </td>
      <td><span class="row555c">0.00</span>    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update to your SCRIPT with the below code.***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row1').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1c = $(this).val() * 25;
        $('.row1c').html((row1c).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row1a').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1ac = $(this).val() * 15;
        $('.row1ac').html((row1ac).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row1b').keyup(function(ev){

        var row1bc = $(this).val() * 10;
        $('.row1bc').html((row1bc).toFixed(2));

    });

   $('.row2').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2c = $(this).val() * 45;
        $('.row2c').html((row2c).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row2a').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2ac = $(this).val() * 25;
        $('.row2ac').html((row2ac).toFixed(2));

    });
    $('.row2b').keyup(function(ev){

        var row2bc = $(this).val() * 20;
        $('.row2bc').html((row2bc).toFixed(2));

    });
  $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row5c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })


  $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row55c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })
   $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      total += Number($(this).parent().next().next().next().find('span').text());
    })
    $('.row555c').text(total.toFixed(2));
  })
});
```

**just changed two lines**
for discount:

```
total += Number($(this).parent().next().next().find('span').text());
```

and for net total

```
Number($(this).parent().next().next().next().find('span').text());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6yvorx9/4/)

Comment: Hai Matee 
Thank you for your kind solutions. Its now working fine
Thank you once again

Comment: mark my answer green tick as a thank :P @Ramchendankarthick

Answer (score 0):

Assign classes to your  elements as below :

```
<td><input type="text" name="pages" class="row1 row1a row1b" /></td>
<td><span class="row1c total1">0.00</span></td>
<td><span class="row1ac total2">0.00</span></td>
<td><span class="row1bc  tota3">0.00</span></td>
```

And

```
<td><input type="text" name="pages" class="row2 row2a row2b" /></td>
<td><span class="row2c total1">0.00</span></td>
<td><span class="row2ac total2">0.00</span></td>
<td><span class="row2bc tota3">0.00</span></td>
```

Functions that calculate totals should look like this :

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.total1').each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).text());
    })
    $('.row5c').text(total.toFixed(2));
});

$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.total2').each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).text());
    })
    $('.row55c').text(total.toFixed(2));
});
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('total3').each(function() {
        total += Number($(this).text());
    })
    $('.row555c').text(total.toFixed(2));
});
```